# oracle spatial compute area of polgons inside a class of polygon group by polygon ID

Tags: oracle, group-by, polygon, spatial

I have a `table pline_sp`, that have a geom column containing `SDO_GEOMETRY` polygons. Each polygon have a class type. I wrote a SQL query to find class `C1` and find all polygons from class `C2` that resides inside of class `C1` and then sum the area of all.

I'm not sure this is the best way but query is as follows:

```
select sum(SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(result.geom, 0.005, 'unit=SQ_KM'))  
from (SELECT a.geom
      FROM pline_sp a,
           (select A.Geom from pline_sp A where A.class='C1') B
      WHERE SDO_RELATE(A.Geom, B.Geom, 'mask=inside') = 'TRUE' 
        AND A.Class='C2') result;
```

There are about 7 polygons from class `C1` in table, each having different `label`.

I want to get sum of polygons area inside it separated by label not sum of all.

I want the result to be like this:

```
Label   Area
--------------
l324     321.54
l543     325.21
```

...

Does it have any solution in SQL or I should write procedure?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my question.
First the SQL could be more readable as follows and by adding `S.label` in `select` and  `GROUP BY S.label` at the end everything will be OK:

```
 SELECT S.label,SUM(SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(M.geom,0.005,'unit=SQ_KM')) 
      from 
        (SELECT P.label,P.geom from pline_sp P WHERE P.class='class1') S,
         (SELECT P.geom from pline_sp P WHERE P.class='class2') M
         WHERE 
         SDO_RELATE(M.geom,S.geom,'mask=inside')='TRUE'
         GROUP BY S.label;
```